# do-while loop using IF

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

I am using if condition statement with a do while loop. I want that everytime when the compiler runs the program it should print the statement in the" IF " till it reaches less then 15 what is happening is that the job is going quite well in do-while loop but the statement in" IF " only printed once? Where am i going wrong. If someone explains the flow it would be really appreciated as i am a beginner. Please see below for the code :

```
package loopexamples2;

public class DoWhileLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;
    if(n<15)

        System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);

    do {
     System.out.println(n);
     n++;
    }
     while(n<10);           
    }
}
```

output--> print value of n is equal to1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: Offtopic: the compiler does not run the program. It compiles it.

Comment: @m0skit0 - You are absolutely correct.  But if you want to be painfully pedantic about it, you could argue that the compiler "runs" the constant expressions so that it put their values into the ".class" file.  (Of course, I would never suggest such a silly interpretation :-) )

Comment: Thanks for correcting I could have been more realistic saying " compiler compilers the programs and JVM runs it "

Answer (score 3):

Your if statement is outside your do while loop. Put it inside the do {} block

```
package loopexamples2;

public class DoWhileLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;

    do {
     if(n<15) {
        System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);
     }
     System.out.println(n);
     n++;
    }
     while(n<10);           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something closer to this:

```
while(n<15) {
    System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);
    n++
}
```

The block of code within `{` and `}` will be run constantly until `n` reaches a value greater or equal to 15.

With your current code, the full print statement is only output once, as it isn't included in your `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks but I already did the ' While ' loop criteria apparently was making  a forceful  example of do while with if. Practically speaking using while is quite straight forward and much better way

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
package loopexamples2;

public class DoWhileLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1;        
        do {
           System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);
           n++;
        } while(n<10);           
    }
}
```

Code flow:

`int n = 1;` Assigns n to 1

`do {` Repeat code between braces from here until `while`.

`System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);` Prints `print value of n is equal to1`

`n++;` Increments n by 1, so n = 2

`} while(n<10);` Is n < 10? Yes so repeat from `do`

`System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);` Prints `print value of n is equal to2`

`n++;` Increments n by 1, so n = 3

`} while(n<10);` Is n < 10? n = 3 so yes, repeat from `do`

*[ ...same thing repeats until... ]*

`System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);` Prints `print value of n is equal to9`

`n++;` Increments n by 1, so n = 10

`} while(n<10);` Is n < 10? n = 10 so no, exit loop.

End of program.

Answer (score 0):

The statement inside the IF is passed only once. Since it is not inside any loop.

The flow of the program is procedural. So the execution is from top to bottom. It first pass the IF block, executes it, procedes to the next line, finds the do-while block which is loop until the while condition is met. Loops only iterates on it's block and not on lines before it.

Answer (score 0):

I explain the workflow, since you are a beginner:

```
    int n = 1;
```

1 is assigned to `n`.

```
    if(n<15)
        System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);
```

The program check if n is less than 15. it is the case, so it  execute the action: print "print value of n is equal to" + n. It only does that once. It's not a while or a for loop that execute a loop repeatedly.

```
    do {
     System.out.println(n);
     n++;
    }
     while(n<10);           
    }
```

Here the program execute everything between the { and the } until n=10.

You are saying "it should print the statement in the" IF " till it reaches less then 15"

Then you need a similar do/while loop:

```
 do {
     System.out.println("print value of n is equal to"+ n);
     n++
 }
 while (n<15);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want that everytime when the compiler runs the program it should print the statement in the" IF " till it reaches less then 15*

Since you are using `n<10` condition in `do while` loop , the loop will not proceed beyond `n=9` . So it won't reach `n=15`.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to put the `if()` statement INSIDE the do while loop. otherwise the program only sees the if once.

the next thing you're doing is in your statement:

```
do {
    System.out.println(n);
n++;
}
while(n<10);
```

you have it only going until `n` is less then 10, you want it to be less then 15.

I assume you wan't it to print out 15 as well so you can change

```
while(n < 10)
```

to

```
while(n <= 15)
```

so all together your code would look like this:

```
package loopexamples2;

public class DoWhileLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;

    do {
        if(n <= 15){
            System.out.println("The value of n is equal to " + n);
            n++;
    } while(n <= 15);
}
}
```

note `<=` means "less then or equal to"

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this any time...
It will be more helpful to you..

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Comment: Definitely, after headfirst it is the next ' headshot' !